# Why does the php not work for my form?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have been trying to make this form validate before sending an email to my company.  It will not validate the form, it will just send it whenever someone clicks submit.  No validation is happening, I don't know what to do about this.

Here is a little of the form

```
<tr>
<td><label for="reason3">Reason for Leaving?</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="reason3" name="reason3" class="c3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<hr size="1.5" color="#000000" noshade></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="maywe">May we contact the employers listed above?<br>
If not, indicate which you do not wish us to contact:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="maywe" name="maywe" class="c3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="additional">Any additonal information you would like us to<br>
consider when reviewing your application?</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="additional" name="additional" class="c3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<hr size="1.5" color="#000000" noshade></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div class="c2">
<hr size="1.5" color="#000000" noshade>
        The above information is true and complete to the best of my knowledge. Should I become<br>
employed by <a href="http://www.creativeurethanes.com/">Creative Urethanes, Inc.,</a> any false statements on this application may be<br>
considered sufficient cause for dismissal.<br>
        I understand that filling out this application does not indicate that there are necessarily any<br>
vacant positions at this time, nor does it in any way obligate this Company.<br>
        I acknowledge that I have read Creative Urethanes' <a href="Memo.html">Memo on Right to Know</a>. <input type="checkbox" name="Yes" value="Yes"><span class="c1"><sup><i>*</i></sup></span><br>
<br></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<hr size="1.5" color="#000000" noshade></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Sign electronically with your full name and SSN.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="electronicsignfn"><u>Full</u> <u>Name</u><span class="c1"><sup><i>*</i></sup></span></label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="electronicsignfn" name="electonicsignfn" class="c3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="electronicsignssn"><u>S.S.N.</u><span class="c1"><sup><i>*</i></sup></span></label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="electronicsignssn" name="electronicsignssn" class="c3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="emailaddress"><u>Email</u> <u>Address</u><span class="c1"><sup><i>*</i></sup></span></label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<hr size="1.5" color="#000000" noshade></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" id="field89" name="field89" class="c3" value="Submit"></td>
<td><input type="reset" id="field90" name="field90" class="c3" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {
$errormsg = "";
if ($_POST[first_name]){
$first_name = $_POST[first_name];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your first name";
}
if ($_POST[last_name]){
$last_name = $_POST[last_name];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your last name";
}
if ($_POST[ssn]){
$ssn = $_POST[ssn];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your Social Security Number";
}
if ($_POST[phone]){
$phone = $_POST[phone];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your phone number";
}
if ($_POST[address]){
$address = $_POST[address];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your address";
}
if ($_POST[city]){
$city = $_POST[city];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your city";
}
if ($_POST[state]){
$state = $_POST[state];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please select your state";
}
if ($_POST[zip]){
$zip = $_POST[zip];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your 5 digit zip code";
}
if ($_POST[position]){
$position = $_POST[position];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter N/A if open for discussion";
}
if ($_POST[wage]){
$wage = $_POST[wage];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter 0.00 if open for discussion";
}
if ($_POST[Emergencycontactname]){
$Emergencycontactname = $_POST[Emergencycontactname];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your emergency contact's name";
}
if ($_POST[Emergencycontactaddress]){
$Emergencycontactaddress = $_POST[address];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your emergency contact's address";
}
if ($_POST[Emergencycontactcity]){
$Emergencycontactcity = $_POST[Emergencycontactcity];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your emergency contact's city";
}
if ($_POST[Emergencycontactstate]){
$Emergencycontactstate = $_POST[Emergencycontactstate];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please select your Emergency contact's state";
}
if ($_POST[Emergencycontactzip]){
$Emergencycontactzip = $_POST[Emergencycontactzip];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your emergency contact's 5 digit zip code";
}
if ($_POST[Emergencycontactphone]){
$Emergencycontactphone = $_POST[Emergencycontactphone];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your emergency contact's phone number";
}
if ($_POST[hightest]){
$highest = $_POST[highest];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your highest level of education";
}
if ($_POST[degree]){
$degree = $_POST[degree];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter N/A if none";
}
if ($_POST[age]){
$age = $_POST[age];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter yes or no";
}
if ($_POST[problems]){
$problems = $_POST[problems];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter yes or no";
}
if ($_POST[shiftwork]){
$shiftwork = $_POST[shiftwork];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter yes or no";
}
if ($_POST[apprenticeship]){
$apprenticeship = $_POST[apprenticeship];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter yes or no";
}
if ($_POST[disabilities]){
$disabilities = $_POST[disabilities];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter yes or no";
}
if ($_POST[ifyes]){
$ifyes = $_POST[ifyes];
}
else{
$errormsg = "if you answered no to above question, put N/A";
}
if ($_POST[accommodate]){
$accommodate = $_POST[accommodate];
}
else{
$errormsg = "if you answered N/A to above question, put N/A";
}
if ($_POST[experience]){
$experience = $_POST[experience];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter yes or no";
}
if ($_POST[ifyes2]){
$ifyes2 = $_POST[ifyes2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "if you answered no to above question, put N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cname]){
$cname = $_POST[cname];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company name";
}
if ($_POST[caddress]){
$caddress = $_POST[caddress];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company address";
}
if ($_POST[cphone]){
$cphone = $_POST[cphone];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company phone number";
}
if ($_POST[ccperson]){
$ccperson = $_POST[ccperson];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter contact person's name";
}
if ($_POST[ctype]){
$ctype = $_POST[ctype];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter type of work";
}
if ($_POST[cwage]){
$cwage = $_POST[cwage];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter wage earned";
}
if ($_POST[cstart]){
$cstart = $_POST[cstart];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter date started";
}
if ($_POST[cend]){
$cend = $_POST[cend];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter date ended";
}
if ($_POST[creason]){
$creason = $_POST[creason];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter reason for leaving";
}
if ($_POST[cname2]){
$cname2 = $_POST[cname2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company name, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[caddress2]){
$caddress2 = $_POST[caddress2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company address, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cphone2]){
$cphone2 = $_POST[cphone2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company phone number, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[ccperson2]){
$ccperson2 = $_POST[ccperson2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter contact person's name, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[ctype2]){
$ctype2 = $_POST[ctype2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter type of work, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cwage2]){
$cwage2 = $_POST[cwage2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter wage earned, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cstart2]){
$cstart2 = $_POST[cstart2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter date started, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cend2]){
$cend2 = $_POST[cend2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter date ended, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[creason2]){
$creason2 = $_POST[creason2];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter reason for leaving, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cname3]){
$cname3 = $_POST[cname3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company name, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[caddress3]){
$caddress3 = $_POST[caddress3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company address, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cphone3]){
$cphone3 = $_POST[cphone3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter company phone number, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[ccperson3]){
$ccperson3 = $_POST[ccperson3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter contact person's name, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[ctype3]){
$ctype3 = $_POST[ctype3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter type of work, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cwage3]){
$cwage3 = $_POST[cwage3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter wage earned, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cstart3]){
$cstart3 = $_POST[cstart3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter date started, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[cend3]){
$cend3 = $_POST[cend3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter date ended, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[creason3]){
$creason3 = $_POST[creason3];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter reason for leaving, or type N/A";
}
if ($_POST[maywe]){
$maywe = $_POST[maywe];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Type names of companies you do not want us to contact, or type, ok all";
}
if ($_POST[additional]){
$additional = $_POST[additional];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Type N/A if you do not have any additional information";
}
if ($_POST[electronicsignfn]){
$electronicsignfn = $_POST[electronicsignfn];
## Heading ##    }
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your full name";
}
if ($_POST[electronicsignssn]){
$electronicsignssn = $_POST[electronicsignssn];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your Social Security Number";
}
if ($_POST[emailaddress]){
$emailaddress = $_POST[emailaddress];
}
else{
$errormsg = "Please enter your email address";
}
else{
if ($errormsg){ //if there is already an error, add next error
$errormsg = $errormsg;
}else{
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: change all your array references like $_POST[phone] to $_POST['phone']

Comment: You probably should also have a concatenation operator instead of an assignment operator when you're checking each form variable, else you'll just end up over-writing previous error messages.

Comment: True, @andrewsi, but it won't stop the script from working.

Comment: @Shomz - which is why it's not added as an answer :)

Comment: :) I gave you +1 there... but I don't know why @Waygood won't make it an answer...

Comment: @Shomz constant phone not found, 'phone' assumed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that need to happen in order for your PHP to read the form data.  First, as Waygood suggested, it is a good idea to change your $_POST values to have single quotes around the passed variable name.

```
//For example:
$_POST[address]; 

// Should change to:
$_POST['address']; //Notice the single quotes around the word address
```

Secondly, as answered by John, there is no reference to the passed **submitted** value in your **html form**, you'll want to add a hidden input in your form (anywhere between your   tags) that holds the value of 1 to make your first statement true in order for the rest of your php code to execute.

```
<!-- Put this input tag anywhere between your opening and closing form tags in your html -->
<form method="POST" action="your_submission_page.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
</form>
```

Finally, it's **good practice** to notify the user of ALL of the errors in the form so that they don't experience error after error before being able to submit the form.  What you should be doing is building a dynamic array of error messages, checking to see if there are any errors and then displaying them all.

```
<?php
    // Create a dynamic array for the error messages and validate everything before sending them back to the form that shows them

    // Here is a sample of your code with the dynamic array built in
    $error_msgs = array ();   
    $error = 0; //Error flag     

    if ($_POST['cwage2']){
        $cwage2 = $_POST['cwage2'];
    } else {
        $error_msgs[] = "Please enter wage earned, or type N/A";
        $errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
    }

    if ($_POST['cstart2']){
        $cstart2 = $_POST['cstart2'];
    } else {
        $error_msgs[] = "Please enter date started, or type N/A";
        $errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
    }

    // Finally at the end, check to see if there are any errors and display them all
    if ($errors > 0) {
        //Display the amount of errors first
        echo "There were " . $errors . " errors in your submission, please correct them.<br/>";

        //Then display your error array
        foreach ($error_msgs as &$msg) {                
            echo $msg . "<br/>"; 
        }
    } else {
        // Add code here to submit the form however you'd like

    }

?>
```

Comment: +1 I would $errors=true; rather than 1

Comment: @Tony Mancini, where would I put the
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />

Comment: Anywhere between your opening <form> tag and your closing </form> tag.

Comment: Waygood, I've added a different perspective to the $errors flag, instead using it as a counter, however, using true as opposed to 1 is better practice.

Comment: @TonyMancini, Let me test that out

Comment: @TonyMancini, so at the last 'else' I want it to be sent to my email, for now at least, what do I type?  Do I type, something like, mailto:heitfieldmichael@yahoo.com?  Or what?

Comment: @TonyMancini, I have a sendmail.php file. I also forgot about it.  I'm guessing, that there is a way to have the php code on the same page as my form?

Comment: @Tony Mancini, yikes. and thanks, it works, but it shows 
There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.
Please enter your first name
There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.
Please enter your last name
etc
Is there a way to have the message show up next to the field?

Comment: @Tony Mancini, Tony my man, are you still there?

Comment: Hi Kiba, sorry, I was away until now.  I've changed the code a bit at the end... the amount of errors shown should be echoed above the foreach loop so that it doesn't repeat.  Sorry about that.  If you want the form to submit to itself use `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` in the ACTION of your form, and then put your php code on the same page, above the doctype declaration.  Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php for sending mail in that last statement where I've mentioned "Add code here to submit the form however you'd like."

Comment: For showing the error next to the box, this is one of those things that needs to be figured out first before coding the form and the error handling. If you want to show the errors next to the boxes I'd recommend using jQuery for that, I've used http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/form-validation-and-hints in the past and it works to my satisfaction.

Comment: @TonyMancini, Like this:

Comment: <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"

Comment: yes, that will post the form to the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a form field named `submitted` and without it your PHP validation code won't be triggered. Try changing:

```
if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {
```

to something more generic like this:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
```

Comment: Tried it, and I had totally forgotten about the 'submitted' lolz.  Didn't help though. I have a submit button but it doesn't start the validation.  I'm not good at php and use a lot of like examples that other people have used, just changed some fields and such.  Other than writing basic html code, which isn't even considered programming, I'm like a 2 year old trying to do algebra

Answer (score 1):

OK @KibaHeitfield

Change references to array elements from:

```
$_POST[first_name]
```

to:

```
$_POST['first_name']
```

Comment: @Waygood, adding the 'first_name' didn't help.

Comment: No. It just prevents PHP warnings.

Comment: AND what if first_name is declared as a constant???? How are you going to debug your code? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

1. there is no if for following else

   else{
       if ($errormsg){ //if there is already an error, add next error
           $errormsg = $errormsg;
       }else{

   ```
   }
   ```

   }
2. $errormsg = $errormsg; doesn't mean anything.
3. Errormsg is assigned but never used. Use echo $errormsg;
4. $_POST[first_name] should be $_POST['first_name']
5. Instead of $_POST['submitted'] use if($_POST['field89'] == 'Submit')
6. Why don't you experiment with a small form and expand when it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply check this way

```
if($_POST){
 //form is posted do your work here
}
```

Comment: Theoretically on the page may exist more than one form. Forms must have prefixes like $_POST['form1']['field1'], and than we must check `if (!empty($_POST['form1']))`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have no way of showing the error. Try adding this to the foot of your php code:

```
echo $errormsg; die();
```

instead of

```
$errormsg = $errormsg;
```

Let us know what happens.

Comment: Still not validating, all it does is go to my, "thank you" page

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a method for the form ("GET","POST")?

Comment: I used the "POST" method