# Displaying Form Failures Next To Form Fields

Tags: php, forms, field, message

This was [formed by TonyMancini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850019/why-does-the-php-not-work-for-my-form), but I need help now.  The form does validate, but, it comes up with a new page that looks like

There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.

Please enter your first name

There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.

Please enter your last name

There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.

Please enter your 9 digit social security number

There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.

Please enter your phone number

There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.

Please enter your address

There were 57 errors in your submission, please correct them.

Please enter your city

etc.

Is it possible to have the errors show up next to my form fields? Or not?

```
<?php
// Create a dynamic array for the error messages and validate everything before sending them back to the form that shows them
// Here is a sample of your code with the dynamic array built in

$error_msgs = array ();
$error = 0; //Error flag

if ($_POST['first_name']){
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your first name";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['last_name']){
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your last name";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ssn']){
$ssn = $_POST['ssn'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your 9 digit social security number";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['phone']){
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your phone number";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['address']){
$address = $_POST['address'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your address";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['city']){
$city = $_POST['city'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your city";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['state']){
$state = $_POST['state'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please select your state";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['zip']){
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your 5 digit zip code";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['position']){
$position = $_POST['position'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter position desired, or type N/A if open for discussion";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['wage']){
$wage = $_POST['wage'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter 0.00 if open for discussion";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactname']){
$Emergencycontactname = $_POST['Emergencycontactname'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's name";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactaddress']){
$Emergencycontactaddress = $_POST['Emergencycontactaddress'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's address";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactcity']){
$Emergencycontactcity = $_POST['Emergencycontactcity'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's city";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactstate']){
$Emergencycontactstate = $_POST['Emergencycontactstate'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please select your emergency contact's state";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactzip']){
$Emergencycontactzip = $_POST['Emergencycontactzip'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's 5 digit zip code";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['Emergencycontactphone']){
$Emergencycontactphone = $_POST['Emergencycontactphone'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter your emergency contact's phone number";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['highest']){
$highest = $_POST['highest'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter your highest level of education";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['degree']){
$degree = $_POST['degree'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter N/A if none";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['age']){
$age = $_POST['age'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['problems']){
$problems = $_POST['problems'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['shiftwork']){
$shiftwork = $_POST['shiftwork'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['apprenticeship']){
$apprenticeship = $_POST['apprenticeship'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['disabilities']){
$disabilities = $_POST['disabilities'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ifyes']){
$ifyes = $_POST['ifyes'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "If you answered no to above question, type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['accommodate']){
$accommodate = $_POST['accommodate'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Type N/A if you answered N/A for above question";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['experience']){
$experience = $_POST['experience'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter yes or no";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ifyes2']){
$ifyes2 = $_POST['ifyes2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "If you answered no to above, type N/A, otherwise describe";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cname']){
$cname = $_POST['cname'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company name";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['caddress']){
$caddress = $_POST['caddress'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company address";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cphone']){
$cphone = $_POST['cphone'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company phone number";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ccperson']){
$ccperson = $_POST['ccperson'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company contact person's name";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ctype']){
$ctype = $_POST['ctype'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter type of work";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cwage']){
$cwage = $_POST['cwage'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter wage earned";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cstart']){
$cstart = $POST['cstart'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter date started";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cend']){
$cend = $POST['cend'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter date ended";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['reason']){
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter reason for leaving";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cname2']){
$cname2 = $_POST['cname2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company name or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['caddress2']){
$caddress2 = $_POST['caddress2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company address or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cphone2']){
$cphone2 = $_POST['cphone2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company phone number or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ccperson2']){
$ccperson2 = $_POST['ccperson2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company contact person's name or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ctype2']){
$ctype2 = $_POST['ctype2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter type of work or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cwage2']){
$cwage2 = $_POST['cwage2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter wage earned or type 0.00 if N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cstart2']){
$cstart2 = $POST['cstart2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter date started or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cend2']){
$cend2 = $POST['cend2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter date ended or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['reason2']){
$reason2 = $_POST['reason2'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter reason for leaving or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cname3']){
$cname3 = $_POST['cname3'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company name or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['caddress3']){
$caddress3 = $_POST['caddress3'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company address or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cphone3']){
$cphone3 = $_POST['cphone3'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company phone number or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ccperson3']){
$ccperson3 = $_POST['ccperson3'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter company contact person's name or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['ctype3']){
$ctype3 = $_POST['ctype3'];
} else {
 $error_msgs[] = "Please enter type of work or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cwage3']){
$cwage3 = $_POST['cwage3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter wage earned or type 0.00 if N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cstart3']){
$cstart3 = $POST['cstart3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date started or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['cend3']){
$cend3 = $POST['cend3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter date ended or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['reason3']){
$reason3 = $_POST['reason3'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter reason for leaving or type N/A";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['maywe']){
$maywe = $_POST['maywe'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Type names of companies you do not want us to contact, or type, ok all";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['additional']){
$additional = $_POST['additional'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Type N/A if you do not have any additional information";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['electronicsignfn']){
$electronicsignfn = $_POST['electronicsignfn'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your full name";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['electronicsignssn']){
$electronicsignssn = $_POST['electronicsignssn'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your 9 digit social security number";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

if ($_POST['emailaddress']){
$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
} else {
$error_msgs[] = "Please enter your email address";
$errors++; //Flag to let the code know that there are errors, used in every case
}

// Finally at the end, check to see if there are any errors and display them all
if ($errors > 0) {
// Display your error array
foreach (    $error_msgs as &$msg) {
echo "There were " . $errors . " errors in your submission, please correct them.<br/>";
echo $msg . "<br/>";
}
} else {
// Add code here to submit the form however you'd like
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional tests are most likely going to evaluate to false everytime.  You probably need to test with isset() or empty() like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
    // a value was posted
} else {
    // error
}
```

or

```
if (!empty($_POST['field'])) {
    // a value was posted
} else {
    // error
}
```

It is possible to have the errors show up next to your input fields, but you need to work on first things first, which is to get your form working correctly.

Comment: I mean it works great, but the error message(s) show up on a new page and you have to click the back button, but then you might now remember the errors you needed to fix.

Comment: I will add that I'm not very fluent with programming language, in fact, I suck at it.